# Fatal error! System out of memory! UNITY 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, overflow, fatal-error, allocation

**I was working in a scene with only some 2d spirtes and recently added a Particle System with one sub emitter with a collision effect. After working and testing it for a few min I always get this fatal error. I don't know why I get this.
My laptop has 16gb of RAM.
Unity version 5.4.1f1 64bits**

ERROR:

Could not allocate memory: System out of memory!

Trying to allocate: 18446743951336546967B with 16 alignment.

MemoryLabel: TempOverflow

Allocation happend at: Line: 177 in
C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Allocator/ThreadsafeLinearAllocator.cpp
Memory overwiew

[ ALLOC_DEFAULT ] used: 40694528B | peak: 0B | reserved: 74448896B

[ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 2097152B

[ ALLOC_GFX ] used: 108085168B | peak: 0B | reserved: 119117128B

[ ALLOC_CACHEOBJECTS ] used: 332752B | peak: 0B | reserved: 10485760B

[ ALLOC_TYPETREE ] used: 493472B | peak: 0B | reserved: 17825792B

[ ALLOC_PROFILER ] used: 29600B | peak: 0B | reserved: 8388608B

[ ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD ] used: 31211B | peak: 0B | reserved: 55017472B

[image: Particle effect and sub emitter options]

Comment: Can you try deleting the cache? If you have one of the latest Unity releases, you can clean it under Edit -> Preferences -> GI Cache.

Comment: Could you include the settings of your particle system in your question as well? And if any, the code relevant to the particle system.

Comment: @Andrea It doesn't help, but thank you anyways :)

Comment: @MXD I added a photo with the options: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIHm9.png

Comment: So any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by deleting the **GI Cache**. You can delete this manually by going to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\`, and deleting the folder called gi cache.